oracle sql developer - HOW TO put together the results of 2 selects that have nothing in common
I have 2 select very long, and I have to put the results together
result first select

result second select

Result desidered

I'd like to understand how to do

We don't post images of data here.

Do a CROSS JOIN.

Use sub-query factoring (WITH) clauses and a CROSS JOIN:
WITH query1 AS (
  <insert_your_first_long_query_here>
),
query2 AS (
  <insert_your_second_long_query_here>
)
SELECT q1.*,
       q2.*,
       TO_CHAR(100 * q2.nombre_montan / q1.nombre_tiers, 'FM990D00')
         AS pourcentage_remplissage_revenus
FROM   query1 q1
       CROSS JOIN query2 q2;


However, if you are calculating a percentage of a total and your second query calculates the individual values and the first query calculates the total of those individual values then you (probably) don't need the first query and can just use the second query and the SUM analytic function:
WITH query2 AS (
  <insert_your_second_long_query_here>
)
SELECT q2.*,
       SUM(q2.number_montan) OVER () AS nombre_tiers,
       TO_CHAR(
         100 * q2.nombre_montan / SUM(q2.number_montan) OVER (),
         'FM990D00'
       ) AS pourcentage_remplissage_revenus
FROM   query2 q2;


In general, whenever you want to expand the column space of your result, you need a join.
As the second result appears to be only one row in size, you could simply cross-join with the original result, as the cross-product of a set of size 1 with any set is of the same cardinality as the latter.  This would produce a result set in which each row has an extra column, and whose total size is the same as the total size of the first select.
I do not have Oracle SQL on hand, but, in SQLite (I believe comma-as-cross syntax is the same), this example looks like so:
sqlite> SELECT a, a_count FROM foo, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS a_count FROM foo);
┌───┬─────────┐
│ a │ a_count │
├───┼─────────┤
│ 1 │ 3       │
│ 2 │ 3       │
│ 3 │ 3       │
└───┴─────────┘


You can nest the one query inside the SELECT clause of the other:
SELECT Nature_Montant, Nombre_Montant,
    (SELECT Nombre_Tires
     FROM ...
    ) As Nombre_Tires,
    Nombre_Montant / (SELECT Nombre_Tires
                      FROM ...
                      ...
                     ) As Pourcentage...
    
FROM ...

But if the inner query is expensive this could be SLOW.
Since the result from the first query will always be the same, a better option is running this as a script or procedure to first get the result into a variable, and then using that variable in the second query.
